# Unexpected mount syscalls when running sudo command

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

I'm working on a program that monitors for mount and unmount syscalls and prints the various arguments of the calls to the terminal. It works ok but I noticed some behaviour that I don't understand where other commands on the system seem to trigger the mount/umount syscalls with parameters that don't make sense.

For example, using bpftrace, I run this command: `bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_mount { printf("%s %s %s %s\n", comm, str(args->dev_name), str(args->dir_name), str(args->type)) }'` . Now if I run a mount command (e.g. `mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /home/tests`) the output on the terminal is as I expect:

```
[root@rhel9-vm]# bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_mount { printf("%s %s %s %s\n", comm, str(args->dev_name), str(args->dir_name), str(args->type)) }'
Attaching 1 probe...
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /home/tests xfs
```

If I open another terminal and try to run any sudo command, I get a lot of `mount` syscalls with empty or unexpected arguments:

```
[root@rhel9-vm]# bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_mount { printf("%s %s %s %s\n", comm, str(args->dev_name), str(args->dir_name), str(args->type)) }'
Attaching 1 probe...
(fprintd)  / 
(fprintd) / /proc/self/fd/3 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/chr /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/dir /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) proc /proc/self/fd/4 proc
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/acpi /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/asound /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/bus /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/fs /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/irq /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/reg /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/reg /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/reg /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/mtrr /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/scsi /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/sys /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/proc/sysrq-trigger /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/dir /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/dir /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/propagate/fprintd.service /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/dir /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root/sys/devices /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /tmp/systemd-private-69f2a28c33e74958aed8c34daf301716-fprintd.s /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/inaccessible/dir /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /var/lib/fprint /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /var/tmp/systemd-private-69f2a28c33e74958aed8c34daf301716-fprin /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd)  /proc/self/fd/4 
(fprintd) /run/systemd/unit-root / 
(fprintd)  / 
(fprintd)  /run/systemd/incoming
```

I don't understand this behaviour. Why would there be any `mount` syscalls for a simple `sudo ls` command? In the short term, I can filter out the unexpected by ignoring any that don't have the file type set but that seems like a bit of a hack. Maybe there is something in the entry flags that would explain it?

The command field (`comm`) from bpftrace mentions `fprintd` although when I look at the calls through a third party kernel driver I see `systemd rhgb --switched-root --system --deserialize 31` as the command.

Is there any reasonable explanation for the behaviour I'm seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, `mount` can do more than mount filesystems - there is also a "bind mount", that mounts a content of a directory to another directory - like a symlink, but different.

In that trace we see the fingerprint scanner daemon (`fprintd`) prepares an isolated container: a process, that can only view a portion of the system and separated from other processes. You can read more on that function of Linux in [man namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html).

In this case, `fprintd` mounts all directories it deems necessary for a future containerized process - once the container is sealed, all other files and directories will become inaccessible for that process. After that it would use [pivot_root](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html) to permanently move the root to a new directory (for that process and its children).

As to why it does that - I cannot say. It seems to be some security measure, but the intricacies of `systemd` is outside of my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you. Looking through the entry flags I can see the MS_BIND and MS_REMOUNT set so it looks like this is exactly what I am seeing.